# How to pass an <ngx-datatable-column> inside a wrapped, by another component, <ngx-datatable>?

Tags: angular, angular-datatables

I have wrapped an `<ngx-datatable>` component, inside a component of mine let's call it `<app-table>`, in order to use some standard configs throughout the application. The problem is that I cannot pas an `<ngx-datatable-column>` inside the  and let it pass indside `<ngx-datatable>`. No errors are thrown, it just ignores the passed element.

I tried `<ng-content>` and `<template>` with `TemplateRef`, with no success. I suspect that `<ngx-datatable>` does not recognize the passed element because it has already been initialized without it.

```html
<app-table [rows]="rows"
           [limit]="page.limit"
           [columns]="columns">
    <ng-container content>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions">
            <ng-template let row="row"
                         let-value="value" 
                         ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <button>...</button>
                <button>...</button>
            <ng-template>
         </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ng-container>
</app-table>
```

Inside app-table.component.ts

```
.
.
<ngx-datatable [configs]="...configs...">
    <!-- The column is never displayed in here -->
    <ng-content select="[content]"></ng-content>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: use TemplateRef to to sent template ...  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

Comment: @MuhammadNasir Thanks for replying, but can you elaborate a little bit more? How can I pass a template and project it inside the `<ngx-datatable>`?

Answer (score 0):

> You can attach a context object to the EmbeddedViewRef by setting
>   [ngTemplateOutletContext]. [ngTemplateOutletContext] should be an
>   object, the object's keys will be available for binding by the local
>   template let declarations.

Change your html.

```
<ngx-datatable [configs]="...configs...">
    <!-- The column is never displayed in here -->
       <ng-template [ngTemplateOutlet]="itemTemplate" *ngIf="itemTemplate" 
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: option }"></ng-template>
</ngx-datatable>
```

Inside the ts file.Access a **TemplateRef** instance by placing a directive on an  element (or directive prefixed with *)

```
  @ContentChild(TemplateRef) itemTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
```

pass value like this

```
<app-table [rows]="rows"
           [limit]="page.limit"
           [columns]="columns">
    <ng-template>
        <ngx-datatable-column name="Actions">
            <ng-template let row="row"
                         let-value="value" 
                         ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                <button>...</button>
                <button>...</button>
            <ng-template>
         </ngx-datatable-column>
    </ng-template>
</app-table>
```

Comment: I'm trying to use this approach but can't seem to get it working, here's my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tw9bq